# Entity Framework doesnt create all columns - code first

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I want to create a Table with 3 columns, one for each property of my Libro entity, but when the table is created it has only two columns, id and Titulo, without my navigation property "Comments"

This is the Entity class

```
public class Libro
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Titulo { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

This is the migration file

```
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Libros",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    id = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1"),
                    Titulo = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Libros", x => x.id);
                });
```

Comment: What do you expect the third column to be? What data type in the database?

Comment: I'm not sure, I was expecting an iterable data type similar to an array but I don't know what that data type would be called in the database.

Comment: A database does not have iterable types. That would be another table.

Comment: What does your Comment type and table look like?

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. The Comment type has the properties id, content and bookId. I was thinking about a column that connects a book with its comments, but it is a 1:M relation so it should connect a book with a whole different table of its comments right? Is it why the column is not created?

Comment: Indeed, if a book can have multiple comments, but one comment is always for one specific book, you would have the book's Id as a column in the table of the comments. That is how database design works for relational databases. You may want to read about database design a little bit, because EF (and other OR mappers) are used to make it easier, you still need good knowledge of what is happening, it's not magic, it doesn't "just work".

Comment: Please get a bit more familiar with relational database structure. That's a prerequisite for working with EF and understanding what it does. What you want is described in the classical [blogs + posts example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/one-to-many).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a database list structure, it is the association structure you create, [click on the link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many) for more detailed information.